# Applying masks in C# + XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, light

How do I apply masks in C# + XNA? I want to create a black map, and a flashlight, that it lights stuff up.

Comment: Nothing yet, can't think of anything how to do it.

Comment: [GameDev.SE] might be a better place for this question.

Comment: I doubt this will help (why it's a comment), but when I did flashlights in my game, I made an overlay of everything with 32x32 (size of the tiles in my game)  black blocks with a transparency of 20% , then I would change their transparency based on how close they were to a light source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pixel shader, that has image and mask as input and "masked image" as output.